# Discord.py Member.activities always returns empty tuple

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is one of the first posts I've made on this site, so apologies if I'm missing anything in my question.

I'm trying to create a bot that keeps track of the songs I've been listening to by accessing my activities. I have this as my intent:

```
intents = discord.Intents( guilds=True,members=True,presences=True)
```

and despite having an activity present on my discord account, this command always returns an empty tuple:

```
async def on_ready(self):
        user = await self.fetch_user(user_id)
        mutual_guild = await self.fetch_guild(user.mutual_guilds[0].id)
        member = await mutual_guild.fetch_member(user_id)
        print(member.activity)
        print("Bot Ready")
```

where `user_id` is a variable containing my discord id. However, when I use `on_presence_update(self, before, after)` I can see my activities, but can't see them in `member.activity`, so I don't think it's an issue with my intents.

I was expecting the activities using `member.activities` and `on_presence_update(self, before, after)` to be the same. Regardless of what I do `member.activities` always returns an empty tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you used `fetch_guild` method.
 In the [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_guild), `fetch_guild` could only get limited amount of information, excluding Guild.channels, Guild.members, **Member.activity** and Member.voice per Member.
Therefore, if you bot caches guilds during startup, then you don't need to make API calls. You could simply use `get_guild` with id to get specific guild. And more importantly, `get_guild` can let you to access all members and their activities.
A suggestion other than the question: it is not a good habit to do stuffs in `on_ready` event. So, consider to move it somewhere else if possible.